# Make a website automatically load in Landscape view on an iPad

Tags: ipad, landscape

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I have created a website and I want it to automatically load in landscape view on the iPad. Is this possible and if so can it be done with javascript or css?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the frame (the Safari window, status bar, URL bar, etc) from inside JavaScript / HTML, but you could wrap your whole site in a div and add the "-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);" attribute when you detect that it's in portrait orientation.

That will display your site in landscape, but the user will probably then rotate the device itself into landscape which would then rotate your content incorrectly oriented relative to the user.  You'd have to detect that using JS and remove the CSS attribute above when you truly are in landscape.  If you're using jQuery or something I could imagine it being relatively easy, but the user may still see a bit of flickering as the content bounces around.